# Samba 4 OpenLDAP authentication issue

Tags: authentication, active-directory, openldap, samba

**What I've done so far**

- Installed DHCP server and bind9 for the local network of clients (the server should act as a gateway)
- built Samba4 from source with bind9_dlz as dns backend
- installed OpenLDAP using `apt-get install slapd ldap-utils`
- changed slapd ports to `390,637` because of samba blocking `389,636`
- imported the samba ldap scheme, initially set up the ldap directory and provisioned the domain
- installed `libnss-ldapd` for ldap authentication (`getent passwd` outputs LDAP users correctly)
- gave samba the admin password to my ldap directory (`smbpasswd -w xxx`)

**The Problem**

I joined a Windows 7 client to the domain and tried to log into a user created with `smbldap-useradd`. I recieve a wrong password message from windows but absolutley no errors/warnings from samba. My test user is really existent in LDAP (checked with `phpldapadmin`), so I assume samba is not correctly talking to ldap. I'm stuck at this point and need some help!

**What I've noticed**

I've set `passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://testsrv.alfr.local:390/` which is not appearing in the output of `testparm` (see underneath).

**Software I'm using**

- Ubuntu Server 12.04 up-to-date
- Samba 4.1.6 compiled from source (official git repository)
- Bind 9.8.1
- slapd 2.4.28
- isc-dhcp-server 4.1

**Configs and Outputs**

- Server host name: `testsrv`
- Domain name: `alfr.local`
- 2 network interfaces, eth0 = DHCP, externally WAN, eth1 = `192.168.25.1` (Server acts as DHCP for this network ranging from 25.50 till 25.254)

Output of `testparm`

```
root@testsrv:~# testparm 
Load smb config files from /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[profiles]"
Processing section "[netlogon]"
Processing section "[sysvol]"
Processing section "[homes]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DC
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    workgroup = ALFR
    realm = alfr.local
    server role = active directory domain controller
    passdb backend = samba_dsdb
    add user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -m '%u' -t 1
    rename user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-usermod -r '%unew' '%uold'
    delete user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-userdel '%u'
    add group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupadd -p '%g'
    delete group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupdel '%g'
    add user to group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -m '%u' '%g'
    delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -x '%u' '%g'
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -w '%u' -t 1
    domain logons = Yes
    os level = 10
    preferred master = Yes
    domain master = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    wins support = Yes
    ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=alfr,dc=local
    ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
    ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap
    ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
    ldap suffix = dc=alfr,dc=local
    ldap ssl = no
    ldap user suffix = ou=Users
    server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, cldap, ldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, smb
    dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver, winreg, srvsvc
    rpc_server:tcpip = no
    rpc_daemon:spoolssd = embedded
    rpc_server:spoolss = embedded
    rpc_server:winreg = embedded
    rpc_server:ntsvcs = embedded
    rpc_server:eventlog = embedded
    rpc_server:srvsvc = embedded
    rpc_server:svcctl = embedded
    rpc_server:default = external
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    map archive = No
    map readonly = no
    store dos attributes = Yes
    vfs objects = dfs_samba4, acl_xattr

[profiles]
    path = /srv/samba/profiles
    read only = No
    create mask = 0611
    directory mask = 0700
    profile acls = Yes
    map hidden = Yes
    map system = Yes
    browseable = No
    csc policy = disable

[netlogon]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/alfr.local/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol
    read only = No

[homes]
    comment = Eigener Ordner
    path = /srv/samba/homes/%S
    read only = No
    create mask = 0611
    directory mask = 0711
    browseable = No
    vfs objects = acl_xattr, full_audit
    full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename
    full_audit:success = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename
```

Output of `ps aux` (cut unimportant stuff out)

```
root@testsrv:~# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       699  0.0  0.0   7272   608 ?        Ss   08:08   0:00 dhclient3 -e IF_METRIC=100 -pf /var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -1 eth
bind       827  0.0  2.8 502280 58392 ?        Ssl  08:08   0:01 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
dhcpd      833  0.0  0.2  14552  4476 ?        Ss   08:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf
openldap  1024  0.0  0.3 722000  6524 ?        Ssl  08:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap://127.0.0.1:390/ ldaps://127.0.0.1:637/ ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fslapd%2fldapi/??
root      1051  0.0  0.0 693092  1172 ?        Ssl  08:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/nscd
nslcd     1075  0.0  0.0 443600  1376 ?        Ssl  08:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/nslcd
ntp       1279  0.0  0.0  25960  1836 ?        Ss   08:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 107:114
root      1595  0.0  2.2 534364 46152 ?        Ss   09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1597  0.0  1.8 538976 38532 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1598  0.0  1.7 539772 35624 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1599  0.0  1.6 536876 33716 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1600  0.0  1.6 534364 34568 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1601  0.0  1.8 534804 37568 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1602  0.0  1.8 538516 37212 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1603  0.0  1.6 534364 34328 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1604  0.0  1.6 537192 33928 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1605  0.0  1.5 534364 32716 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1606  0.0  2.0 534364 41264 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1607  0.0  1.6 534364 33884 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
root      1608  0.0  1.6 534364 33360 ?        S    09:52   0:00 samba start
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
root@testsrv:~# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

# pre_auth-client-config # passwd:         compat
passwd: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # group:          compat
group: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # shadow:         compat
shadow: files ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

# pre_auth-client-config # netgroup:       nis
netgroup: nis
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any security directive in your config file. I assume that you want security=ad. I've spent last month trying to do exactly same thing - use OpenLDAP as main database of user login information.

I've tested few approaches:

1. Samba 4 AD can't trust at the moment (Samba Team will publish soon Samba 4.2 in the time of writing), so u can't use trust mechanisms.
2. Samba 4 in AD as far as I know can't be based on OpenLDAP because lack of schemas needed by Active Directory.
3. I've tired to use software called LSC, which basically allow you to sync user and groups between AD an OpenLDAP. No luck here either. LSC documentation and examples are outdated and not compatible with current release. I've finally managed to get user sync working, but there are few bugs (at least in LSC v2.0 I've tired), when you update password in OpenLDAP, LSC won't catch it. You have to store passwords in plain text to make it work.

For now no Samba AD controller with OpenLDAP as backend. I am planing to stick classic NT domain controller as soon as Samba will support trusts, then I wanna delegate one direction trusts (from samba4 NT DC to Samba4 AD) and use it on AD domain controller with user information located at OpenLDAP.

If someone can find any mistake here, I'll be more than glad to hear it. ;-)

**UPDATE**:
According to Francesco Malvezzi information in Samba 4.3, trust are now supported:

https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.3.0.html

> ### Improved support for trusted domains (as AD DC)
>
> The support for trusted domains/forests has improved a lot.
>
> `samba-tool` got "domain trust" subcommands to manage trusts:
>
> `create`      - Create a domain or forest trust.
>
> `delete`      - Delete a domain trust.
>
> `list`        - List domain trusts.
>
> `namespaces`  - Manage forest trust namespaces.
>
> `show`        - Show trusted domain details.
>
> `validate`    - Validate a domain trust.
>
> External trusts between individual domains work in both ways (inbound
>   and outbound). The same applies to root domains of a forest trust. The
>   transitive routing into the other forest is fully functional for
>   kerberos, but not yet supported for NTLMSSP.
>
> While a lot of things are working fine, there are currently a few
>   limitations:
>
> - Both sides of the trust need to fully trust each other!
> - No SID filtering rules are applied at all!
> - This means DCs of domain A can grant domain admin rights
>     in domain B.
> - It's not possible to add users/groups of a trusted domain
>     into domain groups.

Configuration example:
https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.3.0.html

> Trust relationship is created and can be check using winbind:
>
> `wbinfo -u` -> get local users list
>
> `wbinfo -u --domain=trusted.domain.tld` -> get trusted domain users list (short domain can be used too)
>
> It can also be validated using `--local-dc-username` and
>   `--local-dc-password` switches:
>
> `samba-tool domain trust validate trusted.domain.tld \ 
>   --local-dc-password=trustedAdminPass \  --local-dc-username=administrator \  -U administrator at trusted.domain.tld`
>
> Using Samba's internal DNS make DNS queries forwarding transparent
>   (with the few tools I think about to check).
>
> To be able to connect on machine.A.domain.tld using a user from
>   B.domain.tld you'll have to "Authenticated users" special group to RDP
>   authorized peoples.

I am still waiting until it become available in official channel in my distro (debian 8-9) though.

Comment: update: domain trust has been introduced in samba-4.3.0

Answer (score -1):

I have been making a LDAP server with SAMBA. The problems I faced with SAMBA, and that might been troubling you, are between the configuration of different versions of SAMBA. Are you sure you used the appropriate configuration for your version of samba? It would be very helpful if you copy the .bash_history so I can look for any misconfiguration or even test it on a machine.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have explicit need to use ldap?

I use samba active directory for over a year now and the only problem I have is with timescew.  You should double check that especially when you are using virtualised machines.